# Configure a debezium connector for multiple tables in a database

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I'm trying to configure a Debezium connector for multiple tables in a MySQL database (i'm using debezium 1.4 on a MySQL 8.0).
My company have a nomenclature pattern to follow when creating topics in kafka, and this pattern does not allow the use of underscores (_), so I had to replace them with hyphens (-)

So, my topics names are:

**Topic 1**

```
fjf.db.top-domain.domain.sub-domain.transaction-search.order-status
WHERE
- transaction-search = schema "transaction_search"
- order-status = table "order_status". 
- All changes in that table, must go to that topic.
```

**Topic 2**

```
fjf.db.top-domain.domain.sub-domain.transaction-search.shipping-tracking
WHERE
- transaction-search = schema "transaction_search"
- shipping-tracking = table "shipping_tracking"
- All changes in that table, must go to that topic.
```

**Topic 3**

```
fjf.db.top-domain.domain.sub-domain.transaction-search.proposal
WHERE
- transaction-search = schema "transaction_search"
- proposal = table "proposal"
- All changes in that table, must go to that topic.
```

I'm trying to use the transforms "ByLogicalTableRouter", but i can't find a regex solution that solve my case.

```
{ "name": "debezium.connector",
 "config":
    { 
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"database.hostname": "myhostname",
"database.port": "3306",
"database.user": "debezium", 
"database.password": "password", 
"database.server.id": "1000", 
"database.server.name": "fjf.db.top-domain.domain.sub-domain.transaction-search",
"schema.include.list": "transaction_search",
"table.include.list": "transaction_search.order_status,transaction_search.shipping_tracking,transaction_search.proposal",
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka.intranet:9097",
"database.history.kafka.topic": "fjf.db.top-domain.domain.sub-domain.transaction-search.schema-history",
"snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
"transforms":"RerouteName,RerouteUnderscore",
"transforms.RerouteName.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.regex":"(.*)transaction_search(.*)",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.replacement": "$1$2" 
"transforms.RerouteUnderscore.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.RerouteUnderscore.topic.regex":"(.*)_(.*)",
"transforms.RerouteUnderscore.topic.replacement": "$1-$2" 
    }
}
```

- In the first transforms,im trying to remove the duplicated schema
  name in the topic routering.
- In the second transforms, to replace all
  remains underscores _ for hiphens -

But with that, I'm getting the error below, which indicates that it is trying to send everything to the same topic

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaBuilderException: Cannot create field because of field name duplication __dbz__physicalTableIdentifier`

How can i make a transform that will forward the events of each table to their respective topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removing the schema name

> In the first transforms,im trying to remove the duplicated schema name in the topic routering.

After transforamtion with your regex you'll have two dots, so you need to fix it:

```
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.regex":"([^.]+)\\.transaction_search\\.([^.]+)",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.replacement": "$1.$2"
```

2. Replace underscores for hiphens

You can try to use [ChangeCase](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/ChangeCase.html#changecase) SMT from [Kafka Connect Common Transformations](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common).

Comment: Didnt work :(
First i tried like this
"transforms":"RerouteName,changeCase",
"transforms.RerouteName.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.regex":"([^.]+)\\.transaction_search\\.([^.]+)",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.replacement": "$1.$2",
"transforms.changeCase.type" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.ChangeCase$Value",
"transforms.changeCase.from" : "LOWER_UNDERSCORE",
"transforms.changeCase.to" : "LOWER_HYPHEN"
and getting the error: Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: ts-ms

Comment: "transforms":"RerouteName,RerouteUnder",
"transforms.RerouteName.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.regex":"(.*).card_acquisition.(.*)",
"transforms.RerouteName.topic.replacement": "$1.$2",
"transforms.RerouteUnder.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.RerouteUnder.topic.regex":"(.*)_(.*)",
"transforms.RerouteUnder.topic.replacement": "$1-$2"
and the error was
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaBuilderException: Cannot create field because of field name duplication __dbz__physicalTableIdentifier

Comment: The first error comes from the AvroConverter, You could use the JSONConverter instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use JSON in this project, I need to use Avro.

Comment: Tell me please is everything work as you want without transformations (with exception of topic naming of course)?

Comment: Yes, my problem is only with topic routing because of the topic name patterns I have to follow.
When I do the local test (where I can use any name in the topic and do not need to use any transforms), it works perfectly.

Comment: This work for me. Thanks Iskuskov!!
      "transforms.topicCase.type": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.common.ChangeTopicCase",
      "transforms.topicCase.from": "LOWER_UNDERSCORE",
      "transforms.topicCase.to" : "LOWER_HYPHEN",

Comment: Great news! You're welcome! If my answer was helpful, please vote up :)